# Insert double Value for equation in PDF with pdfbox in Java

Tags: java, double, pdfbox, fieldlist

I'm struggling with a little Java Project:
I made a Program which autofills a PDF Formular. Mostly everything works fine for me, but there is a Problem: In this PDF Formular (which is given from my company, so I have to deal with this document) is a equation Field, which is used for calculation the Costs from Number of Items and the single Price. When I insert the Price of a single Item as a String to my PDF

```
    public void setEinzelpreis(String Einzelpreis)
{
    try {
        fieldList.get(30).setValue(Einzelpreis);
...
```

[image]

There should be the single Price on the empty field in the first row. The last Cell of the row is auto-calculated by the pdf.
When I Click in the PDF in the "empty" Field, the Value appears:
[image]
When I click to another Field, the Value disappears. This is my Problem.
I'm getting the FieldList via pdfbox and the Code for getting my fieldList of the PFD is:

```
try {
    pdfTemplate = PDDocument.load(template);
    PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog = pdfTemplate.getDocumentCatalog();
    PDAcroForm acroForm = docCatalog.getAcroForm();
    if (acroForm != null)
    {
    // Get field names
    fieldList = acroForm.getFields();
    
    }
...
```

So, can anybody tell what I'm doing wrong? Maybe the PDF wants a double Value for the equation and I am giving a String? But I don't know how to write a double in the FieldList. Thanks a lot for every hint!

Edit:
The PDF File which I'm using:
https://1drv.ms/b/s!Av6exjPNXlgOioouAuXL6QV4eUGkqg?e=ocfhvC

And this is the file I generated:
https://1drv.ms/b/s!Av6exjPNXlgOioovK-HuRuXW2aRy_w?e=D1ZCA8

The strange thing is: when I change the value in the document by hand, everything acts normal, even with a different Document Viewer.

Comment: as the value appears some times, it seems the value inserted. But I guess the problem related with formatting of cells, like foreground-colors. background-color, color etc.

Comment: Normally the content should appear before you click into the field. I'm wondering if there are some javascript effects when you use Adobe Reader (PDFBox doesn't use javascript). Can you share the PDF? What PDFBox version are you using?

Comment: I added the Link to the PDF File. I am using Fox It reader for viewing the files.

Comment: In the result file there is a value in the field "Einzelpreis in € exkl USt1" but the actual field to fill in would be "Einzelpreis in € exkl USt1.0.0.0.0". (Yes, the form structure in the file at hand is weird to say the least.) I'll try and check whether you simply filled the wrong `PDField` (addressing fields by index in the field array is generally a bad idea...) or whether PDFBox in this weird form structure attached the value to the wrong field.

Comment: If you retrieve the field by name, see my answer, you'll get the field "Einzelpreis in € exkl USt1.0.0.0.0". The method `getFields` you use is documented as *`This will return all of the documents root fields`*, so it won't return fields like "Einzelpreis in € exkl USt1.0.0.0.0" anyways.

Comment: @mkl - Hm, i can't track your assertion about "Einzelpreis in € exkl USt1.0.0.0.0". When I track the name of the fields via:
'code'
    fieldArray[i] = sField.getFullyQualifiedName();
I get the expected "30 is: Einzelpreis in € exkl USt1"
When I set the value via this name:
'code'
    int q=0;
    for (String f : fieldArray) {
    PDField field = acroForm.getField(f);
    if (f.contains("Einzelpreis in € exkl USt1")) {
    String value = SEinzelpreis;
    field.setValue(value);
    }
    q++;
    }
I get the exact behaviour like adressing the field via the index.

Comment: Does your `fieldArray` include `"Einzelpreis in € exkl USt1.0.0.0.0"`? If it does not, then you ignored what I said. If it does, you probably have to update PDFBox, see @Tilman's comment to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the AcroForm form structure in your PDF is weird. It looks like someone used a graphical form generation tool he did not understand and clicked, dragged, dropped, copied, ... until the form in a viewer did what he wanted, not caring about it having become difficult to maintain.

In particular the Einzelpreis fields have a completely unnecessary structure of intermediate and final fields, e.g.

[image: screen shot]

Thus, the field `Einzelpreis in € exkl USt1` (the '€' is missing in the tree above) is not the one to fill in, it's merely an intermediary field. The actual form field to fill in is `Einzelpreis in € exkl USt1.0.0.0.0`.

Unfortunately you in your code simply grab the 30th field in the field list returned by `PDAcroForm`, and this field happens to be the intermediary field `Einzelpreis in € exkl USt1`; as an intermediary field it has no visible widgets of its own, so your `setValue` call doesn't change the visible Einzelpreis.

The JavaScript instruction calculating the Gesamtpreis uses the value from the final field, too:

```
AFSimple_Calculate("PRD", new Array ("Anzahl1", "Einzelpreis in € exkl USt1.0.0.0.0"));
```

But as the field value is inheritable and none of the .0 fields has an own value, the calculation sees the 100 once form calculation has been triggered and uses it.

Thus, you should fill the `Einzelpreis in € exkl USt1.0.0.0.0` field instead. And the more secure way to retrieve it is not by index in a field list but by name:

```java
PDField fieldByName = acroForm.getField("Einzelpreis in € exkl USt1.0.0.0.0");
```

*(excerpt from [FillInForm](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/form/FillInForm.java#L447) test `testFill2020_04BeschaffungsantragEinzelpreis`)*

After filling that field, the "100" should be visible in your form.

The remaining problem that the Gesamtpreis value is not calculated is due to the fact already mentioned by @Tilman in a comment to the question: *PDFBox doesn't use javascript*. Thus, you have to calculate those values yourself and update the fields in question accordingly.

If you need to know the correct name of a form field, you can do as Tilman proposed and use the PDFBox PDFDebugger. If you hover over the field there, it will display the name in the status bar at the bottom.

By the way, the `AcroForm` method `getFields` won't return the field required here anyways. As documented in its JavaDocs, this method *will return all of the documents **root fields***, no fields further down in the hierarchy, at least not immediately. (From the user perspective the method name `getFields` is a misnomer. It is accurate, though, from the PDF specification perspective as the corresponding entry in the **AcroForms** object has the key **Fields**.)

Beware, though, you probably will have to update your PDFBox version. In earlier versions PDFBox did not update appearances of fields with JavaScript actions (believing some JavaScript would fill it in anyways). I used the current 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT in which that behavior has been changed.

Comment: This was done in PDFBOX-4977 but this is not released yet, snapshot at https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox-app/2.0.21-SNAPSHOT/

Comment: @mkl
woah, thank you so much, this worked for me (almost). Now the Problem is the not updated Calculation of the Gesamtpreis in €
(exkl. USt.) Any further suggestions?

Comment: *"Now the Problem is the not updated Calculation"* - as Tilman already commented before, *PDFBox doesn't use javascript*. Thus, you have to do the calculations manually and set the calculated fields accordingly. Or you add a JavaScript action to the document that triggers calculation of all calculated fields at startup. But then your PDF would only display the values in JavaScript-enabled viewers.

Comment: ok, but the Problem is, I don't know the correct FieldName for Gesamtpreis in € (exkl. USt.) and the name for addition-field at the bottom of this upper table. Which Software do you use look at the tree structure from the "Einzelpreis in € exkl USt1" field?

Comment: you can use PDFDebugger and hover over the field, then it will tell the name

Comment: It's "Gesamtpreis in € (exkl. USt.)_1.0.0.0.1".

Comment: Hey Guys,
you are awesome and make this community so good. Great Hint with the PDFDebugger!  Everything is fine for me, have a great weekend!